# How to suppress specific Warnings in Java with Gradle in build.gradle file?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, suppress-warnings

I have a number of "Type safety" warnings in Java and I don't want to suppress them all since its across a number of files and packages. To suppress those warnings I need to suppress "Unchecked" in the java class.

How do I configure build.gradle file so that when I build the project those "Unchecked" warnings of category Type safety will be ignored and the output log wont show those warnings?
Thank you.